# Use of .data() in jquery along with <a> tag

Tags: jquery

```
if ( $( "<a>" ).data( "a-b", "a" ).removeData( "a-b" ).data( "a-b" ) ) 
{
    $.fn.removeData = (function( removeData ) {
    return function( key ) {
        if ( arguments.length ) {
            return removeData.call( this, $.camelCase( key ) );
        } else {
            return removeData.call( this );
        }
    };
    })( $.fn.removeData );
}
```

When I downloaded a plug in I found these set of statements in it . What is happening When this set  of statements get executed .what is the meaning of the `if` condition in the `if` statement . Kindly please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *arguments* object is a local variable available within all functions.You can refer to a function's arguments within the function by using the arguments object. This object contains an entry for each argument passed to the function, the first entry's index starting at 0.

In the above case its checking if any arguments are passed to the function and *removeData* function is called with or without parameters .